# Where did clojure.contrib.string/partition go?

Tags: string, clojure, clojure-contrib

Ok, I am mildly confused about the whole `clojure.contrib` reorganisation.

I identified [clojure-contrib.string/partition](https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib/blob/bacf49256673242bb7ce09b9f5983c27163e5bfc/src/main/clojure/clojure/contrib/string.clj#L197) as the function that I need.
However the last commit is 4 years ago and apparently everything from `clojure.contrib` moved to individual repositories.

Supposedly `clojure.contrib.string` moved to `clojure.string`, well except the `partition` function. I just want to know if I am not overlooking something very obvious before I copy the   old code into my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes indeed. It looks like that it was dropped during the migration to `clojure.string` namespace.

If I were you, I will simply copy `clojure.contrib.string/partition` to my codebase.